# python threading is stop

Tags: python, concurrency, python-multithreading

I want to make a process like A run in 40ms one time all the way,and it products some datas.Then B need to get the datas to make something and it cost 180ms one time.And I need C to get the solved datas from B and it can show the datas 40ms one time all the way.That is C is later than A for just 180ms,but it is keep 40ms one time moving like the A.What should I do?

```py
import threading
import queue
import time

num=0
def s1(q, lock):
    global num
    while True:
        num = num + 1
        if not q.full():
            lock.acquire()
            q.put(num, 0.02)
            lock.release()
        time.sleep(0.04)

def s3(q, lock):
    while True:
        try:
            lock.acquire()
            x = q.get(timeout=0.02)
            lock.release()
            print(x)
            time.sleep(0.04)
        except queue.Empty:
            lock.release()
            continue

q = queue.Queue(10)
lock = threading.Lock()

f1 = threading.Thread(target=s1, args=(q, lock))
f3 = threading.Thread(target=s3, args=(q, lock))

f1.start()
f3.start()
```

it was the first time I try to remake the code with ITC and it success.Then I add another module to approach my idea like the following codes but it just show the few numbers and show like the picture.what is the error with my code?what should I do?Does it has logical error?

```py
import threading
import queue
import time

# Define a queue shared between threads
data_queue = queue.Queue(10)
show_queue = queue.Queue(10)
lock=threading.Lock()

# Add a value to the data_queue every 40ms
def producer(data_queue,lock):
    num = 0
    while True:
        try:
            lock.acquire()
            data_queue.put(num, 0.01)
            lock.release()
        except queue.Full:
            lock.release()
            pass
        num += 1
        data_queue.put(num)
        time.sleep(0.04)

# every 40ms make a process to get a value from data_queue and process it and put it into the show_queue.every process spend 180ms alone
def consumer(data_queue,show_queue,lock):
    while True:
        try:
            lock.acquire()
            x = data_queue.get(timeout=0.01)
            lock.release()
            # use Timer object to make a new process every 40ms
            threading.Timer(0.04, consumer, args=(data_queue,show_queue,lock)).start()
            time.sleep(0.18)
            try:
                lock.acquire()
                show_queue.put(x, 0.01)
            except queue.Full:
                pass
            lock.release()
        except queue.Empty:
            lock.release()
            time.sleep(0.04)
            continue



# get a value from the show_queue every 40ms
def display(show_queue,lock):
    while True:
        try:
            lock.acquire()
            x = show_queue.get(timeout=0.02)
            lock.release()
            print(x)
            time.sleep(0.04)
        except queue.Empty:
            time.sleep(0.04)
            lock.release()
            continue

# create and start three sub threads
t1 = threading.Thread(target=producer,args=(data_queue,lock))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=consumer,args=(data_queue,show_queue,lock))
t3 = threading.Thread(target=display,args=(show_queue,lock))
t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()

# Wait for the three sub threads to complete execution
t1.join()
t2.join()
t3.join()
```

[it stop with nothing error throw[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xX7a.png)

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Can you create a [mre]?

Comment: I want to capture a 25-frame video stream from a camera and perform object detection on each frame using a function that takes 180ms to run and return results. To achieve real-time detection and display, I want to try Python's multithreading and concurrency, so that each frame can be processed and displayed with a delay close to 180ms.

Comment: Ok, so what's going wrong? What have you tried? What errors are you encountering? What do you want us to do about it?

Comment: I make a new try and modified my question